# Transacciones SQL

Tags: sql-server

Necesito hacer una verificación de que se haya realizado correctamente una transacción, siendo que dicha transacción trabaja en varios sistemas, es decir si necesito dar de Alta, en un varios sistemas, a un mismo usuario y uno o todos esos sistemas no se encuentran disponibles como puedo hacer para que el sistema principal reintente hacer la transacción sin tener que repetir el ingreso de datos?

Comment: Claramente a la pregunta le falta información, por ejemplo, "¿de que lenguaje estamos hablando?" (SQL-server) no es el que da de alta la informacion, dado el caso, eres tu que limpia el formulario de entrada, si lo que haces es un formulario web, ajax te permite el envio del formulario sin recargar la pagina por lo tanto tampoco recargar los campos, o bien aquel que procesa el formulario al "retornar error" llama nuevamente al formulando enviandole parametros de entrada que se convertiran en los valores "por defecto" al construir el formulario (mas un parametro de descripcion de error) por ej.